# Decorator pattern with nested classes

Tags: php, decorator

I have structure of classes

```
class engine {
    function show() {
        return "some html code";
    }
}

class car {
    private $engine;
    function __construct() {
        //some logic
        $this->engine = new engine();
    }

    function show() {
        $code = "****";
        $code .= $this->engine->show();
        return $code;
    }
}
```

Each class have output in html, svg, txt. I tried to use decorator pattern to make htmlCar, htmlEngine, svgCar, svgEngine and adding more outputs without editing engine and car classes. But how to do it without changing $this->engine = new engine(); to $this->engine = new htmlEngine(); ?

Comment: inject it. `function __construct(engineInterface $engine) {`